# How can I display PDF file in javascript which is available as only a base64 string

Tags: image, pdf, base64

This is the code I'm using to display images on my screen. It seems to be working fine except for PDF files.

Is it possible to do it without having to convert the string to a PDF file again, saving it and then displaying it?

`FileContent` has data in `base64` string.

```
<%
  HashMap hmap2 = null;
  hmap2 = (HashMap)request.getAttribute("valuesMap");
  String bh7 = (String)hmap2.get("FileContent");
%>

<img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=bh7%>"/>
```

Comment: I use this method of displaying PDF all the time. Are you setting the mime in the src attribute to " application/pdf"? Are you sure the PDF is in Base64?

Comment: It is supported only in some browsers.

Comment: Yes the pdf is in Base64.I'm setting it to application/pdf but it still doesnt work. Using IE11